# Dir returning nothing after going into functions and subs

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()


    StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\Desmond\VBAProject\Raw\")

    While StrFile <> ""

        Debug.Print StrFile & "Entering"

        If StrFile Like "*xls*" Then 'check that current file is excel

            Select Case True
            '1
            Case (StrFile Like "*Hong Kong*")

            newSheetName = "Honggg"
            Call searchThroughWorkBook(wb, sPath, StrFile, newSheetName)

            '2
            Case (StrFile Like "*London*")

            newSheetName = "Londonnn"
            Call searchThroughWorkBook(wb, sPath, StrFile, newSheetName)

            Case Else

            Debug.Print "Nope!!!"

            End Select

        End If

        StrFile = Dir
        Debug.Print StrFile & "   Just before i exit, i am going to search for next"

    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub

Function searchThroughWorkBook(ByRef wb As Workbook, ByVal sPath As String, ByVal StrFile As String, ByVal newSheetName As String)      

   ' Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & StrFile)

        For Each wsSource In wb.Sheets
            Debug.Print wsSource.name ' Check sheet name for something you want
            If wsSource.name = "USD Bal Input" Then

            Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\Desmond\VBAProject\Test2.xlsx")

           If Dir(targetPath & "USDReport.xlsx") <> "" Then
                Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\Desmond\VBAProject\USDReport.xlsx")

            Else
                'Create workbook if dont exist
                AddNewWorkbook ("USDReport")
                Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(targetPath & "USDReport")
                'Call openWorkBookDialog

           End If

                wbTarget.Close SaveChanges:=True

                Exit For

            End If
        Next wsSource

    wb.Close False ' close workbook and don't save changes

End Function
```

I use StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\Desmond\VBAProject\Raw\") to get the files in that folder and loop through them to do something. If the file contains the word hong kong, I go into the function to do some things. However, when I come back out, instead of StrFile = Dir containing the next file in the folder, it returns an empty string. There are more files in the folder. Why is this happening? is it something to do with the way Dir works or some scope issue? Please help thanks

Comment: Do you call `Dir` again anywhere in the code inside the loop?

Comment: Actually I have a If Dir(targetPath & "USDReport.xlsx") <> ""  in the function to check if the file exist in my folder. Does it affect?

Comment: Yes, Dir is a static function, each call with parameter reset its state. You cannot use it recursively.

Comment: I suggest you use Dir in a loop initially to build an array of the file names, then loop through that array.